# If a line through the centroid $G$ of $\triangle ABC$ meets $AB$ in $M$ and $AC$ in $N$, then how to prove that $AN\cdot MB+AM\cdot NC=AM\cdot AN$ .

Tags: geometry

If a line through the centroid $G$ of $\triangle ABC$ meets $AB$ in $M$ and $AC$ in $N$, then how to prove that $AN\cdot MB+AM\cdot NC=AM\cdot AN$ .

Answer (score 0):

Divide both sides by: $AM \cdot AN$ and you'll get:

$$\frac{MB}{AM} + \frac{NC}{AN} = 1$$

Let $A_1,B_1,C_1$ be feet of perpendiculars on line $a$ from vertices $A,B,C$ respectively. Thus $\triangle AA_1M$ and $\triangle BB_1M$ are simular, so do $\triangle AA_1N$ and $\triangle CC_1N$. From the simularity we have:

$$\frac{MB}{AM} = \frac{BB_1}{AA_1} \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{NC}{AN} = \frac{CC_1}{AA_1}$$

So the equation becomes:

$$BB_1 + CC_1 = AA_1$$

which has already been proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657567/distances-to-line-passing-through-the-centroid-of-triangle)